# A button with comment having already clicked will not show up the next time user opens app

Tags: android, button, sharedpreferences, visibility

I want that a button with comment having already clicked will not show up the next time user opens app. I searched on google and understood that I should use shared preferences but I don't know how to use shared preferences in app.

I question how to use sharedpreferences for visibility button?

Comment: where is the question ? what did you already do ? do you have anything ? no body will give you solution

Comment: @Mir Why you didn't accept my *laborious* edit on your post but copy & pasted it as your own edit? I lost my chance to get reputation for my labor, in vain. :(

Comment: @Mir Ok, next time you have some edit by someone, you have better accept edit at first, then you add some information over it (the revised post).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you use shared prefrences :

```
public class AppPrefrances {
protected static AppPrefrances INSTANCE;
private static SharedPreferences prefs;

public static AppPrefrances getInstance(Context context) {
    if (INSTANCE == null) {
        INSTANCE = new AppPrefrances();
        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    }

    return INSTANCE;
}


public void setClicked(String c) {
         //click should be unique
        prefs.edit().putString("click", c).apply();
    }

    public String getClicked() { 
        // 0 is the default value
        return prefs.getString("click", "0");
    }
}
```

Then from inside the activity :

```
Button comment = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
if(AppPrefrances.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getClicked().equals("1"))
    {
comment.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}

    comment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          AppPrefrances.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).setClicked("1");
        }
    });
```

**Shared prefrences will get erased if clear data was chosen from the app's information**